# How to insert a c# datetime var into SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlcommand

Here is the code:

```
string ConnectionString= @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; 
Initial Catalog=notepad; Integrated Security=SSPI ";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString); 
con.Open();
string strEvent = TextBoxEvent.Text;
string strDate = Calendar1.TodaysDate.ToShortDateString();
string strInsert = "insert into notepad (time, event) values (strDate, strEvent )";
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(strInsert, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

the time is `smalldatetime` in SQL Server 2005

When I run this program, an error occurrs like this:

> The name "strDate" is not permitted in
>   this context. Valid expressions are
>   constants,  constant expressions, and
>   (in some contexts) variables. Column
>   names are not permitted.

but if I replace the `strDate` with `2010/05/22` like this:

```
string strInsert = "insert into notepad (time, event) values ("2010/05/22", strEvent )";
```

the program will run correctly.

I am puzzled with this problem and turn for help to you.

Answer (score 5):

You should use parametrized queries for inserting data into SQL Server, and you should put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into using blocks - try something like this:

```
string ConnectionString= @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; 
Initial Catalog=notepad; Integrated Security=SSPI ";

string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO dbo.Notepad(time, event) VALUES (@Date, @Event)";

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Calendar1.TodaysDate;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Event", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextBoxEvent.Text.Trim();

   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
```

Also, this is mixing your database access code with your UI code (retrieving data from textbox and calendar control) - this is a bad practice - you should separate this into two steps:

1. grab the current values from the UI in your code-behind file
2. pass them to a data layer which handles data access without ever directly touching any UI controls

Answer (score 2):

All the methods here said are good but I prefer the following one because its has an edge over the other ones

```
DataAccess DAB = new DataAccess();
ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();
string SQL = " insert into notepad (time, event) values (?,?) ";
arrList.Add(new DataAccessBlock.DataAccess.Parameter("@time",  DbType.DateTime, 30, ParameterDirection.Input, "", strDate ));    
arrList.Add(new DataAccessBlock.DataAccess.Parameter("@event", DbType.String, 50, ParameterDirection.Input, "", strEvent ));

DAB.ExecuteScalar(SQL, CommandType.Text, arrList);
```

Comment: Yep. Avoid converting the datetime value into a string in the first place, and you avoid all kinds of issues. (And also, yes, use parameters. Unfortunately, I can only +1)

Comment: The `?` parameter placeholder will not work with the standard ADO.NET database provider - you need to use named parameters like `@Date` and `@Event`.

Answer (score 1):

This statement below is wrong because you are actually including strDate instead of substituting its value.

```
string strInsert = "insert into notepad (time, event) values (strDate, strEvent )";
```

What you need to do is write as follows:

```
string strInsert = "insert into notepad (time, event) values ("+strDate+"," +strEvent+)";
```

This will substitute strDate and strEvent with the actual values at runtime.

****This approach however is NOT recommended because it is prone to SQL injection attacks ****

Comment: WARNING: This will open the doors to SQL Injection attacks !! You should **NEVER EVER** just concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead - **ALWAYS!**